# Unity C# programmatically modify asset import settings using AssetImporter with Presets

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I'm building a custom asset importer that reads asset settings from a JSON file then applies those settings to the asset in the Unity project. I need to apply those settings on a range of assets.

I have created an editor window with a button click to test my code before implementing it into the main project.

The button click event:

```
private void ButtonClick()
    {
        string path = "Assets\\Audio";

        var assetPaths = HelperFunctions.FindAssetsByType<AudioClip>(path, false);

        for (int i = 0; i < assetPaths.Count; i++)
        {
            AudioClip audioClip = AudioClip.Create("", 128, 2, 8000, false);

            Preset preset = new Preset(audioClip);

            var importer = AssetImporter.GetAtPath(assetPaths[i]);

            bool result = preset.ApplyTo(importer);

            Debug.Log(result);
        }
    }
```

As you can see I have created a blank audio clip in which I am using to model the preset.
I am then loading the AssetImporter for the targeted asset using the path returned by `FindAssetByType` which returns the path of my asset, for example: `"Assets/Audio/myaudiofile.mp3"`

The debug.log returns False, ie a failure to apply.

I am also not able to access certain properties of the AssetImporter programmatically, as see below:

[image: AssetImporter variable]

Why is the AssetImporter failing to apply my new asset preset, and why am I not able to access the properties detailed in the screenshot in code?

```
'AssetImporter' does not contain a definition for 'defaultSampleSettings'
```

I have also tried modifying `FindAssetsByType` to return the object returned by the `AssetDatabase` as follows:

```
T currentAsset = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<T>(currentPath);
```

This results in the `Debug.Log` returning true, but the preset is never applied.
You can see this code commented out below

Here is how I search for assets:

```
public static /*List<T>*/ List<string> FindAssetsByType<T>(string path) where T : UnityEngine.Object
    {
        List<string> assets = new List<string>();
        //List<T> assets = new List<T>();

        string searchString = string.Format("t:{0}", typeof(T));
        searchString = searchString.Replace("UnityEngine.", "");

        string[] guids = AssetDatabase.FindAssets(searchString, new string[] { path });

        List<string> paths = AssetGuidToPath(guids);

        foreach (var currentPath in paths)
        {
            T currentAsset = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<T>(currentPath);

            //assets.Add(currentAsset);
            assets.Add(currentPath);
        }

        return assets;
    }
```

Surely there needs to be a way to accomplish this? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Well, the [AssetImporter class](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetImporter.html) does not have a property called "defaultSampleSettings" since the AssetImporter class is just the base class for all asset importers. As you can see in your screenshot the actual class is ["UnityEngine.AudioImporter"](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioImporter.html). So you just need to downcast your asset importer in order to access this property.

Don't forget to call [SaveAndReimport](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetImporter.SaveAndReimport.html) after you applied some changes to the importer.

Note that applying custom settings to asset importers is usually done with an [AssetPostProcessor](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetPostprocessor.html). Though I think your approach should work as well if you call SaveAndReimport